# Couchbase geospatial bounding box query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

As far as I know, couchbase has support for geospatial data, but I am not sure how to use this.

Does anybody know, if it is possible to query for elements which are inside a bounding box via N1QL `SELECT` statement in couchbase?
If yes, how would a `SELECT` statement look like, to query with a bounding box for the elements in the following json?

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "Bermuda Triangle",
    "area": 1150180
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [-64.73, 32.31],
        [-80.19, 25.76],
        [-66.09, 18.43],
        [-64.73, 32.31]
      ]
    ]
  }
}


{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "Flemish Diamond",
    "area": 2947
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [3.55, 51.08],
        [4.36, 50.73],
        [4.84, 50.85],
        [4.45, 51.30],
        [3.55, 51.08]
      ]
    ]
  }
}


{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "Research Triangle",
    "area": 252
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [-78.93, 36.00],
        [-78.67, 35.78],
        [-79.04, 35.90],
        [-78.93, 36.00]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couchbase Geospatial queries are only supported through Geospatial Views, not N1QL queries.

You would need to create Geospatial View for your coordinates and query it via the Views API.

You can see more information on Geospatial Views in the Couchbase Server documentation: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/indexes/querying-using-spatial-views.html

It is *technically* possible to emulate a geospatial query using N1QL, however it would not be backed by a spatial index and would incur a significant performance penalty - especially for polygon data like you've supplied. You can see an article on how to do this with point data here: https://dzone.com/articles/speed-up-spatial-search-in-couchbase-n1ql